# Impossibility to transform coordinates in degree with sf [R]

Tags: coordinate-system, r, coordinates, sf

I would like to convert coordinates from two different CRS on R with the package `sf`

|  | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DATUM | ETRS89 | BELGIAN DATUM 72 |
| Ellipsoid | GRS80 | HAYFORD24 |
| Projection | None | LAMBERT [1972] |
| Coordinates | GEOGRAPHIC | PLANE |
| Unit | degree+minute | meter |

The conversion from data with degree to meter works properly with this code :

```
d = st_as_sf(d, coords=c("lon","lat"), crs="EPSG:4258" )
dt = st_transform(d, "EPSG:31370")
```

However, when I use it with degree + minutes, I obtain empty points...

(As example, a point with lat: 536.1314 and long: 4943.265 should give an output of x: 229332.264 y: 525235.654)

The problematic dataset:

```
d <- structure(list(lat = c(4943.26460468966, 4943.264349, 4943.264298, 
4943.26419, 4943.26397666667, 4943.2637825), lon = c(536.131357103448, 
536.1306775, 536.13063, 536.13047, 536.130253333333, 536.1299975
), z = c(400.473048275862, 400.2688, 400.183, 400.08975, 399.863333333333, 
399.82925)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am also joining an example of data also in ETRS89 but which is working properly (in degree):

```
d <- structure(list(name = c("12112", "12201", "12202", "12203", "12208", 
"12209"), lat = c(50.0855877916667, 50.0855997333333, 50.0856167121212, 
50.0856117666667, 50.0856332380952, 50.0855853833333), lon = c(4.55540004166667, 
4.55512903333333, 4.55519089393939, 4.5551871, 4.55524742857143, 
4.55543285), id = c("12112", "12201", "12202", "12203", "12208", 
"12209")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I do not know how to signify the `sf::st_as_sf()`, I am in degree + minutes

**EDIT**

As example, a point with lat: 536.1314 and long: 4943.265 should give an output of x: 238942.84 y: 46236.164 (using the software cConvert)

[image]

Comment: Are you certain about the CRS of your problematic dataset? for a geographic degrees based CRS I would expect values somewhere within -180 / +180 range. Your values are out of it by far...

Comment: @JindraLacko yes it is correct. I have added in edit an example of conversion done in a software

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numbers in your data frame are not in degrees:

```
> d
       lat      lon        z
1 4943.265 536.1314 400.4730
2 4943.264 536.1307 400.2688
```

It looks like 4943.265 should be 49 degrees 43.265 minutes. You'll need to convert this to decimal degrees which will be 49 + (43.265/60) which is 49.72108.

To compute this you'll need to take the residue and modulus by 100 and work it out. Here's a useful function:

```
getdec = function(x){x%/%100 + (x%%100)/60}
```

then do:

```
d$latfix = getdec(d$lat)
d$lonfix = getdec(d$lon)
```

Now make a spatial data frame

```
s = st_as_sf(d, coords=c("lonfix","latfix"), crs=4258)
```

and transform:

```
> st_transform(s, 31370)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 238941.1 ymin: 46233.94 xmax: 238942.7 ymax: 46235.49
Projected CRS: Belge 1972 / Belgian Lambert 72
       lat      lon        z                  geometry
1 4943.265 536.1314 400.4730 POINT (238942.7 46235.49)
2 4943.264 536.1307 400.2688    POINT (238941.9 46235)
3 4943.264 536.1306 400.1830 POINT (238941.9 46234.91)
4 4943.264 536.1305 400.0897 POINT (238941.7 46234.71)
5 4943.264 536.1303 399.8633 POINT (238941.4 46234.31)
6 4943.264 536.1300 399.8293 POINT (238941.1 46233.94)
```

Which is close enough to what you expected.

I'm not sure this will work for negative numbers, but you should be okay with Belgium which is conveniently all in the (+,+) quadrant.